Software Generate Label
My software is generating a label and pulling almost all the information I want, but when printing, it assigns a default expiration date to nearly all items. How can I correct this so that the correct expiration date is displayed for each specific item?


<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    $code = htmlspecialchars($data['code']);
    $quantity = htmlspecialchars($data['quantity']);
    $totalLabels = htmlspecialchars($data['totalLabels']);

    $servername = "000.000.000.00";
    $port = "0000";
    $username = "Testing";
    $password = "exp";
    $service_name = "exp";

    $conn = oci_connect($username, $password, "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = $servername)(PORT = $port)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=$service_name)))");

    if (!$conn) {
        $e = oci_error();
        echo json_encode(['success' => false, 'message' => $e['message']]);
        exit;
    }

    $sql = "SELECT mvs.pro_in_codigo, epr.pro_st_descricao, epr.uni_st_unidade, mvs.mvs_st_loteforne, mvs.mvs_dt_validade
            FROM Testing.est_movsumarizado mvs, Testing.est_produtos epr 
            WHERE epr.pro_in_codigo = mvs.pro_in_codigo 
            AND epr.pro_in_codigo = :code
            ORDER BY epr.pro_in_codigo";

    $stmt = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
    oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':code', $code);
    oci_execute($stmt);

    if ($row = oci_fetch_assoc($stmt)) {
        $expiryDateFormatted = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($row['MVS_DT_VALIDADE']));
        $labelContent = "
        <div class='label'>
            <p class='header'><strong>PRODUTO/ITEM:</strong></p>
            <p class='large-text'>{$row['PRO_ST_DESCRICAO']}</p>
            <div class='content'>
                <div class='left-section'>
                    <p class='header'><strong>CÓDIGO:</strong></p>
                    <p class='large-text'>{$row['PRO_IN_CODIGO']}</p>
                </div>
                <div class='right-section'>
                    <p class='header'><strong>QTD / CAIXA:</strong></p>
                    <p class='large-text'>{$quantity}</p>
                </div>
                <div class='left-section'>
                    <p class='header'><strong>DATA VAL:</strong></p>
                    <p class='large-text'>{$expiryDateFormatted}</p>
                </div> 
            </div>
            <p class='lot'><strong>Lote: </strong>{$row['MVS_ST_LOTEFORNE']}</p>
            <div class='print-counter'>{pageNumber}</div>
            <div class='bottom-section'></div>
        </div>";

        echo json_encode(['success' => true, 'labelContent' => $labelContent]);
    } else {
        echo json_encode(['success' => false, 'message' => 'Produto não encontrado.']);
    }

    oci_free_statement($stmt);
    oci_close($conn);
}
?>


I need it to have the correct expiration date when I print it.
correct information
the wrong information that appears on the label

It looks like $row['MVS_DT_VALIDADE'] is in a format that strtotime can't parse - do you have an example?

What would be an example, for this subject the format in the database is in DATE but it still doesn't pass

It seems that the date format may be the issue.
PHP's strtotime() function only supports a limited number of formats, you can correctly parse the date using the below function:
function parseDate(string $date): string
{
    // create a date object using the 'd/m/y' format
    $tmp = date_create_from_format('d/m/y', $date);
    if (!$tmp) {
        // There was an error parsing the date
        return 'NA';
    }
    // return the correctly formatted date
    return $tmp->format('d/m/Y');
}

echo parseDate($row['MVS_DT_VALIDADE']);

The reason for using this function is to correctly create a date object using the date format in your database (d/m/y), then convert it to the requested format (d/m/Y). The function above returns 'NA' if there was an error parsing the date.
